# Spring Cloud Config Server - Basic Auth not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cloud, config

This question is about securing Spring Cloud Config server with basic auth.

The purpose of this project is to provide a git backed config service.  Everything is working up to the point where I want to start introducing security.

The tutorial I am following indicates that just by adding the spring-cloud-starter-security dependency to Maven, that it should introduce basic authentication on the endpoints.  However even with the dependency in place, when I call the service via Postman (for example) :

localhost:8888/s1rates/dev

I get the same successful results as before, where I was expecting the call to fail with an auth error.

My relevant files are below.  I created this project with the spring starter project in STS.  I have rebuilt the project and restarted the spring boot application (in the STS Boot dashboard).  I have also tried adding the following lines to the end of application.yml, with and without the ‘path’.

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
    path: /**
```

All of the research I’ve done seems to indicate this should work (or in this case not work) without further configuration.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

My IDE is:
Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201712210947
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)

Here is a copy of my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pluralsight-springcloud-m2-configserver-git</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>pluralsight-springcloud-m2-configserver-git</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Config Server with Git</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here is my application.yml

```
---
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls
          search-paths:
          - 'station*'
          repos:
            perf:
              pattern:
              - "*/perf*"
              uri: https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf
              search-paths:
               - 'station*'
```

and here is my main class…

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class PluralsightSpringcloudM2ConfigserverGitApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PluralsightSpringcloudM2ConfigserverGitApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: After days of puzzling over this I finally tried back leveling spring-boot-starter-parent to 1.5.3.RELEASE. I was using the 1.5.9.RELEASE version.  By doing this, basic authentication was enabled when the spring-cloud-starter-security dependency was added.  I tested this by stepping up through the versions and the problem starts with version 1.5.4.RELEASE.  I suspect that the root of the issue is that the spring-security.version is updated to 4.2.3.RELEASE in the spring-boot-starter-parent update to version 1.5.4.RELEASE.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation that states that this behavior was changed on purpose and I still haven't figured out how to set up basic authentication in any version past 1.5.3.RELEASE.

Any further thoughts would be appreciated.  If I don't hear from anyone in a few days I'll post this as an answer, although it feels incomplete to me.